# For x in Arra give me None at the end of Array

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am trying to make a Blackjack game to practice OOP in Python.
And I have this clases:

```
class Deck:
    suits = ('Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades', 'Clubs')
    ranks = ('Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace')
    Points = {'Two': 2, 'Three': 3, 'Four': 4, 'Five': 5, 'Six': 6, 'Seven': 7, 'Eight': 8, 'Nine': 9, 'Ten': 10,
              'Jack': 10, 'Queen': 10, 'King': 10, 'Ace': 11}

    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = []
        for suit in self.suits:
            for rank in self.ranks:
                self.deck.append(rank + ' of ' + suit)
        self.shuffle()

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.deck)

class Hand(Deck):
    cards = []  # start with an empty list as we did in the Deck class
    value = 0  # start with zero value
    aces = 0  # add an attribute to keep track of aces

    def add_card(self, my_card):
        self.cards.append(my_card)
        self.cards = list(filter(None, self.cards))
        if self.adjust_for_ace(my_card):
            self.value += self.calculate_points(str(my_card).split(' ', 1)[0])
    def print_cards(self):
        for card in self.cards:
            print(card)
```

when I call my Hand.print_card after adding cards in Hand class I receive the following result:

```
King of Spades,
Five of Spades,
None
```

Can someone explain please why I get None at the end?

Comment: Well somehow you have a `None` at the end of your `self.cards` iterable OR you are doing a print somewhere on a function you call that returns nothing such as `print(my_func(some_val))`. But you don't show all your code so we cant help you any more than that.

Comment: Where do the commas come from also?

Comment: I just edited my question with more code

Comment: I am a beginner  in programming, and I will be glad if I will receive feedback for my code(what is wrong and what I can improve in writing code cleaner)

Comment: if method doesn't return any value, by default it returns None, like in your case.

Comment: card is = ['King of Spades', 'Five of Spades']

Comment: @Marius can you share the calculate_points and adjust_for_ace function, it may be something messed up there